# Eigenvalues of a Permutation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm stuck on the following problem for my Linear Algebra class:

Let $\pi:\{1, \ldots, n \} \rightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$ be a bijective map (permutation). Let $f_{\pi}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by $f_{\pi}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) := (x_{\pi(1)},\ldots,x_{\pi(n)})$. Determine the set of eigenvalues of $f_{\pi}$.

I know that in general for a square matrix $A$, the set of real eigenvalues of $A$ is given by $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\mid \det(A- \lambda I) = 0\}.$

I've figured out that the matrix representation of $f_{\pi}$ with respect to the standard ordered basis will have rows that contain all $0$s except for a $1$ in one column; this column will be different for each row. However, I can't figure out how to get the eigenvalues from there. Please advise.

Comment: Observe that $\pi^m=\operatorname{id}$ for some $k\ge1$. What does that tell you about $f_\pi^k$ and $\lambda^k$?

Comment: do you mean that $\pi^k =$ id for some $k \geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, I noted mid-typing that I had to avoid the use of my favorite name $n$ - and did so inconsistently :)

Comment: Are you supposed to include complex eigenvalues or aren't you? If not, then the question is much easier to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on Igor Rivin's answer:

Cycle decompositions work as follows.  Suppose you have:

$$
\begin{array}{c} 1 \mapsto 4 \\ 2\mapsto6 \\ 3\mapsto1 \\ 4\mapsto3 \\ 5\mapsto5 \\ 6\mapsto2 \end{array}$$

Then you have three cycles:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
1\mapsto4\mapsto3\mapsto1 \\[10pt]
2\mapsto 6\mapsto2 \\[10pt]
5\mapsto5
\end{array}
$$

They're "cycles" because the return to their starting points.  The cycle decomposition is just the list of cycles.  The cycle decomposition would usually be written something like this: $(1,4,3),\  (2,6),\ (5)$.

Now consider the vector $(a,0,a,a,0,0)$.  The vectors in the 1st, 4th, and 3rd positions are the same, so this vector would be mapped to itself.  It is thus an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.  You get one of those for each cycle.

Now consider
$$
(a,0,b,c,0,0)\mapsto (b,0,c,a,0,0)\mapsto (c,0,a,b,0,0)\mapsto(a,0,b,c,0,0),
$$
returning to the starting point.  This is a $120^\circ$ rotation.  It therefore has an eigenvalue whose cube is $1$, thus $\cos120^\circ+i\sin120^\circ= e^{i\pi/3}$.

Think about $\left(1,0,e^{-i2\pi/3},e^{-i\pi/3},0,0\right)$, and think about why I wrote the components in that order.  There's also a reason why I put a minus sign there, which I missed the first time.

Comment: When you wrote $(c,0,a,b)$, did you mean to write $(c,0,a,b,0,0)$? Also, how did you conclude that the rotation is $120^{\circ}$?

Comment: Typo fixed.  If it's a rotation at all, it has to be $120^\circ$ because it returns to the starting point after exactly three iterations.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use the cycle decomposition of your permutation.

**EDIT** See Michael Hardy's answer for a careful explanation of this method.

Comment: hmm...I don't know what those are, this is only a linear algebra course and they haven't taught us about cycle decompositions...I'll try looking it up.

Comment: @justin: In several of your math courses, you will need to employ techniques you learned elsewhere.

Comment: I've written an answer elaborating on cycle decompositions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! Could not have done it better myself!

Answer (score 4):

For an analysis of the case over $\mathbb{C}$, see Michael Hardy's answer.

**Hint:** compare $\|x\|$ to $\|f_{\pi}(x)\|$.  What does this tell you about the eigenvalues of $f_\pi$?

---

**Example:** take $f(x,y) = (y,x)$. We note that $f(1,1) = (1,1)$, corresponding to an eigenvalue of $1$, and $f(1,-1) = -(1,-1)$, corresponding to an eigenvalue of $-1$.

Comment: I think the norm of each is the same....and we're just working over the reals...so since $\|x\| = \| f_{\pi}(x)\|$, we can conclude that if $x$ is an eigenvector, then the corresponding eigenvalue is $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Yeah, you've got it. From there, you'd need example(s) to show that it can be both $1$ and $-1$. See my latest update.

Comment: Alright, that sounds good!

Comment: The eigenvalue is a complex number whose norm is $1$.  If it's _real_ then it's $1$ or $-1$, but it might not be real.  In that case, it's $e^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$, since those are the only complex numbers whose norm is $1$.

Comment: That depends on whether your definition of eigenvalues includes complex numbers. From the phrasing of the question, it seemed that OP was only looking for real eigenvalues. Your explanation of how to find the set of complex eigenvalues is enlightening, but seems beyond the demands of an introductory linear algebra course.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am also aware that in the complex case, the restriction $|\lambda| = 1$ that my observation produces is a necessary but not sufficient condition on $\lambda$ to be a potential eigenvalue since, as your answer demonstrates, we must have $\lambda = e^{\theta i}$ where $\theta$ is some rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @justin regarding your suggested edit: if we consider all the real eigenvalues of permutations for a fixed $n \geq 2$: all permutations will have an eigenvalue of $1$, but some will also have an eigenvalue of $-1$.  This is true whether or not $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: For a more precise answer as to which permutations have $-1$ as an eigenvalue, we'll have to follow Michael Hardy's reasoning. A permutation will have eigenvalue $-1$ if and only if, when that permutation is decomposed into disjoint cycles, one of those cycles has even length.

Comment: @justin also, feel free to unaccept my answer and accept Michael's, if you feel that his answer is more deserving. He was certainly more thorough.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom okay, thanks for letting me know. I wasn't sure what the right etiquette would be.